# When I save a file the chrome open automatically, how to disable?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I'm using vscode and i have app created by create-react-app.
When i save the file and the webpack server is running, the chrome automatically open.
I couldn't found any solution online.

Comment: It is a feature built in `create-react-app` itself. Try changing the tag to `react` or `create-react-app`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is related to create-react-app

- Create file .env in the same directory where your package.json lives
- Insert this line BROWSER=none to the file and save it run nom start

and web browser will not be opening anymore.

Credits: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/873